# Fetching information from public catalog using Python and BeautifullSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have a problem with urllib2/beautifulSoup. I try to read some information about us patents from the web. To be exact I need to fetch the information about when the application was filed. This information lies in the sentence:

> This application claims the priority of U.S. Provisional Appl. Ser. No. 60/515,559, filed Oct. 29, 2003, the entire disclosure of which is specifically incorporated herein by reference.

This sentence is not a part of any specific tag so I thought it might be good to use regexp on whole HTML (tried some other ways but none worked) so I wrote something like that (I already use BeautifullSoup to get some other informations):

```
url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=7442851.PN.&OS=PN/7442851&RS=PN/7442851"

request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
patent_data = bs(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())

#1
r = re.compile("[A-Z][a-z]{2}\. \d+, \d\d\d\d")
txt = r.findall(str(patent_data))
print txt

#2
print patent_data
```

There are two parts to describe the problem:

1. I run regexp and try to find matches but resulting variable txt is empty list...
2. When I try to simply print whole html I see that the result is not complete (it ends with `(...)<center><b>Other References</b></center> <tr><td></td></tr></br></table></hr></hr></p></hr>`).

Is there any limit of how much data it might download? How can I overcome it?

[Answer to clj]
I do not use proxy on my own - however I don't know if my internet provider has something or not... As for code and info, here's the result:

```
print "info: ", r.info(); 
print "code: ", r.getcode()

output:
info:  Server: NetAnswer Server 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

code:  200
```

One more thing: I use Python 2.7.5 on Win7 64bit if it matters...

Comment: Try to see what actually gets downloaded before you pass the response to BeautifulSoup (just in case its parser chokes on the HTML) by printing the response directly: `print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()` is the result still incomplete?

Comment: Yes, it is still incomplete. The strange thing is that when I try to print urllib2.urlopen(request).read() I get the end of response and when I print patent_data I get beginning of the response - both cases the result is incomplemplete and does not containt the part I need. I also tried to use requests library instead of urllib2 and have the same problem... :/

Comment: That is quite odd! When I run your code (or use `curl`) I get the full page contents. I am guessing that everything looks ok in your browser? Do you have any proxy set up or perhaps a transparent proxy that is interfering with your request? Print statement #1 returns the following for me: `['Apr. 21, 2000', 'Apr. 21, 2000', 'Jul. 19, 2003', 'Oct. 22, 1999', 'Apr. 20, 2004', 'Nov. 21, 2003', 'Nov. 21, 2003', 'Oct. 29, 2003']`... perhaps look at the headers/status code `response = urllib2.urlopen(request); print response.info(); print response.getcode()`

Comment: @clj: I added result of response.info and response.getcode in edit...

Comment: Your code works for me. I was thinking timeout at first, but by default the timeout is infinite, so that's not the problem. Have you tried the same code on a different computer or internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

use requests and it works perfectly fine

```
import requests
import re

url = "http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=7442851.PN.&OS=PN/7442851&RS=PN/7442851"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
r = re.compile("[A-Z][a-z]{2}\. \d+, \d\d\d\d")
txt = r.findall(str(data))
```

output:

['Apr. 21, 2000',
 'Apr. 21, 2000',
 'Jul. 19, 2003',
 'Oct. 22, 1999',
 'Apr. 20, 2004',
 'Nov. 21, 2003',
 'Nov. 21, 2003',
 'Oct. 29, 2003']

Answer (score 0):

The example code (with the required imports) actually works for me too (OSX python 2.7.2):

```
['Apr. 21, 2000', 'Apr. 21, 2000', 'Jul. 19, 2003', 'Oct. 22, 1999', 'Apr. 20, 2004', 'Nov. 21, 2003', 'Nov. 21, 2003', 'Oct. 29, 2003']
```

I have unicode set below my shebang line, but it works with or without that.

What if you remove the `bs()` around the `urllib2` statement? Is your output still truncated?

```
patent_data = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

I get the same search results using this text result rather than the Beautiful Soup object.

In the raw data, the only mention of `Other References` I find doesn't match what you say is the end of your truncated string...

```
  <br /> <center><b>Other References</b></center> <tr><td><align><br />Liu C. et al.
```

After that there are a lot of single and double quotes in the string, which could cause parsing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this strange behavior, neither imagine this is an encoding issue, as I get only 7-bit-ASCII characters response.
Assuming this is caused by your special environment (IDE ?) with larger text (ca. 170 K bytes response):

Did you try to split it down like

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
for i, line in enumerate(response):
    print "[%4i] %s" % (i, line),
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem with bs4, but don't see a problem parsing the response of `urlopen(...).read()` directly. The document may seem incomplete but in fact there is a closing `</HTML>` tag followed by some other tags.

Looking at the page source in firefox shows the same malformed HTML document. I guess this is just a document bs4 cannot handle.

```
>>> txt = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
>>> print txt[txt.index("/HTML"):]
/HTML>
<P><A  HREF=/></A>
<A  HREF=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm></A>
<A  HREF=/netacgi/nph-Parser?SectSect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=netahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r==54285IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=/netaicon/PTO/hitlist.gif border=HIT_LIST]></A>
```

Finally I tried bs3, it appears to parse the document correctly, a least `r.findall(str(BeautifulSoup(txt)))` returns the same list as parsing `txt` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I can't get BS4 to parse what's coming back. I'm not in a position to install BS3, so I'm kind-of at a dead-end here.

But: urllib2 most definitely seems to be retrieving the document without any trouble.

At least part of your problem (based on what's in the question) is that you're taking the downloaded data and running it straight into BS.

Instead of

```
patent_data = bs(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
```

try something like

```
patent_html = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
patent_data = bs(patent_html)
```

patent_html is really just a string of the HTML you're getting back. I strongly suspect that's fine, and patent_data just looks funny because BS is doing something in its **str** method to make the output more readable.

If that's the case, that's why converting it to a string and trying to scan it with a regex fails: it's scanning the truncated string, failing to find what you're looking for, and that's that.

It *might* be worth taking BS out of the picture completely and just scanning the original raw string (patent_html in my example) with the regex. With all the usual caveats that you can't really process HTML with a regex because the text is not regular.